# Google maps satellite view

Tags: google-maps, maps, openstreetmap

I'm using the *google maps API* with *openstreetmap* (see the following example code),

I'd like to add the google **satellite** view too.

How can this be accomplished?

```
var tilesMapnik     = new GTileLayer(copyOSM, 1, 17, {tileUrlTemplate: 'http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.png'});
var mapMapnik = new GMapType([tilesMapnik],G_NORMAL_MAP.getProjection(), "îôä");


map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), { mapTypes: [mapMapnik] });
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(32.08, 34.82), 12);

map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
```

Explanation about using openstreetmap with google maps:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Google_Maps_Example

Comment: "i'm using the google map openstreetmap" can you point us where, cause that's new :)

Comment: I've added an example of the code I'm using. you can see it working in http://www.shvoongmap.co.il/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to add the satellite option to your Google Map, try this:

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), { mapTypes: [mapMapnik, G_SATELLITE_MAP] });
```

Alternatively, you can also use this:

```
map.addMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP);
```

Comment: +1 Chris has the correct answer.  You can find a working example here: http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo12

Answer (score 1):

i think he want to add 2 tabs
one is the openStreetMapData
and  the seconf is google satelite data

like in this site.

http://www.shvoongmap.co.il/

the first tab on the map that writing in hebrew is the openStreetMap data
and the others that writine in english is the google data.

Comment: Not sure how this is an answer to the question and wonder why it was voted up.  Probably best to keep this kind of commentary to the comments.