# using gps on a static map in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

I have a map view in my application and I am able to show the current GPS location on this map easily enough. However I want to be able to offer an offline capability or at least a limited connectivity option.

I decided the best way to do this would be to use a static google map but as i have to use webview to display this and it doesnt extend mapactivity is there anyway i can still get the mylocation overlay to work with a static map? Or do i need to always have that connection for live maps?

Comment: Seems even though google have added the option to download maps on maps for android. I may have to use open street map .

Comment: Using open street maps now with the google satelite view added as seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437780/google-maps-satellite-view. Thankyou for your time anyone who looked into this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could get their location at the time they last had connectivity and pass the coordinates to the static map api to place [marker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Markers) on map image.

Then you could implement a LocationChangedListener and OnLocationChanged (and if connection) reload the static map with the new location marker.

Also you don't have to use Webview, I've used static map images as URL in [AysncImageView](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid/blob/master/GreenDroid/src/greendroid/widget/AsyncImageView.java) (but you could just use a standard Imageview and use something like [AQuery](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/#Image_Loading) to download Async)